# MVC Routing bogus URLs allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I am currently using MVC Routing and `MvcSiteMapProvider`. I have just noticed something which I am unsure about:

```
[Route("mypath/{param1}/{param2}/{param3:int}/", Name = "myaction")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My Thing", ParentKey = "myparent", Key = "myaction", PreservedRouteParameters = "param1, param2, param3")]
public ActionResult myaction(string param1, string param2, int param3)
{
    mymodel model = gd.getmydata(param3);
    var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
    node.Title = model.name;
    node.ParentNode.Title = location;
    node.ParentNode.RouteValues["param"] = location;

    return View(model);
}
```

When I test the url is how I designed it:

```
http://localhost:12345/mypath/param1/param2/param3
```

However if I bastardise the URL with drivel in param2 or param3 the view still resolves with no error. Only by changing mypath or param3 does it 404:

```
http://localhost:12345/mypath/drivel/param2/param3
http://localhost:12345/mypath/param1/drivel/param3
```

Am I missing something? Should I have parameter validation in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens in the URL parameter of the route act like variables. The way you have your route configured, it will always match any URL starting with `mypath/` and containing 3 additional segments. The route does not care what values are put into those segments, it will make them into route keys named `param1`, `param2`, and `param3` containing whatever values are in the actual URL.

If you want the route *only* to match the URL `/mypath/param1/param2/param3`, you will need to use literal route segments.

```
[Route("mypath/param1/param2/param3/", Name = "myaction")]
```

But then, since your `param3` segment is an integer value and your URL contains a string, it is difficult to tell what you are trying to achieve. If you declare it an integer, you must place an integer in the URL or you will get an error.

```
/mypath/param1/param2/123
```

Another thing to note if you are using literal segments in your URL is that they are not converted into route values, so there is no need to use `PreservedRouteParamters` in that case.

So, if you declare your route with variables, it should not be a surprise that any value works. If you want an explicit route, declare it with literal segments. If you want variables but want to restrict the route to a certain range of possible values, then you need to use route constraints.

Comment: Hello. What i am trying to achieve is the URL to list a location ("essex") in param1, a product description in param2 ("show") and the database id in param3 (1234). The URL should be mypath/essex/show/1234. These values will always change so literal will not work. Can I constrain using a List<item>.Contains?

Comment: There are a couple of different options. One would be to make a [RegEx route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) or [custom route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) for each segment. Or you could put logic right in your controller (or a service that is injected into it) to constrain it and return a 404 not found if the values don't match an existing possibility. You could also do both.

Comment: Thank you. I'll start in the controller.